# How to cast "Object" to an unknown custom data type/class object?

Tags: java, object, reflection, casting

I have a function that returns data type 'Object'.

```
public Object myMethod(){}
```

The returned object could be one of many different objects i've defined. For example lets say it returns a objectX.

The place where the function is called and thus we returned back to does

```
objectX tmp = methodThatReturnsSomeObject();
```

This works fine. Regardless of what object i return, as long as i cast the returned object it into the correct object. in this case:

```
objectX tmp = (objectX)methodThatReturnsSomeObject();
```

My problem is that this function is being used in an environment with a bunch of reflection going on. Im iterating through all the attributes of a class using

```
Field[] atts = differentObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields(); 
att[i].set(differentObj, val);
//where val is (TYPE of att)methodThatReturnsSomeObject()
```

i dont necessarily know what kind of object tmp will be because at different points of the iteration it could be an int, String, or another custom object.

Is there some way i can say "whatever class tmp currently is, cast the return of methodThatReturnsSomeObject() into that?

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why you need cast here? [getClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) method returns real (aka runtime) type, [set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) method accepts parameters of `Object` type - there should be no compile-time error.

Comment: Well, originally i wanted to do something like ObjectX tmp = (atts[i].getClass())methodThatReturnsSomeObject(), but that didnt work.  I figured i if i need a strict cast for a direct setting of the object, that using .set() would need a strict cast aswell. But your right! .set does accept Object types, no cast required and it works. Thanks!

Comment: `Field.set(…)` *does* the necessary cast. The only difference is that it will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` instead of a `ClassCastException` when the type is incompatible. If you want to check beforehand, you can use `att[i].getType().cast(val)`. That will throw a `ClassCastException` for wrong types.